# Azure: Parameter 'requestid' value is invalid

Tags: azure

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Speech API as documented here: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/GetStarted/GetStarted-cURL

I have a key and I authenticate fine. When I try to use the service I get this error:

```
Parameter 'requestid' value '1234844532343434' is invalid.
```

I've tried different types of numbers and strings with no luck. What format is Azure looking for in requestid?

My test script looks like this:

```
token="..."
requestid="1234844532343434"

curl -v -X POST "https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?scenarios=smd&appid=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5&locale=your_locale&device.os=your_device_os&version=3.0&format=json&instanceid=your_instance_id&requestid=${requestid}" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" -H 'Content-type: audio/wav; codec="audio/pcm"; samplerate=16000' --data-binary @man1_nb.wav
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation [`here`](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/API-Reference-REST/BingVoiceRecognition#InputParam), the `requestid` parameter's value should be a `GUID`.

[image]

Please try using that.